# Populating an Auto-Incremented ID created through VB.net from a Parent table to multiple child tables in SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

New to VB.net and have been trying to get this to work for a while. As the code stands right now, I'm only able to update each table separately which makes sense but I need help getting an ID from a newly created record to the child tables in my DB. My tables are already set up with PKs and FKs and my connection string has `...foreign keys=true;` in it. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
...Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
            cmd.Connection = myconnection

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into dbo_DataLog (ProductionDate,ProductionOrder,StyleID) values (@ProductionDate,@ProductionOrder,@StyleID)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductionDate", dtpDate.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductionOrder", txtProdOrder.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StyleID", StyleID)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

            Dim cmd2 As New SQLiteCommand
            cmd2.Connection = myconnection
            cmd2.CommandText = "Insert into dbo_WeightAndWidth (LabTech_ID,PunchWeight,OverallWidth,UsableWidth,GSM) values (@LabTech_ID,@PunchWeight,@OverallWidth,@UsableWidth,@GSM)"
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabTech_ID", "5")
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PunchWeight", txtPW.Text)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OverallWidth", txtOW.Text)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsableWidth", txtUW.Text)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GSM", txtGSM.Text)

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd2.Parameters.Clear()

            myconnection.Close()...
```

I have done a lot of searching and can't seem to get anything to work; I know it's a pretty crappy query as is since it's just a repeat of the original.

Please assist if you're able to do so!

Edit:
Changed up my code to consolidate it and used `Dim dataID As String = "Select seq from sqlite_sequence where name='dbo_DataLog'"`and executed that to get utilize the temp table the SQLite uses.

```vb
Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
        cmd.Connection = myconnection

        'look up dataID that was just executed
        Dim dataID As String = "Select seq from sqlite_sequence where name='dbo_DataLog'"
        Dim mycmd As New SQLiteCommand(dataID, myconnection)
        Dim value As Object = mycmd.ExecuteScalar()

        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into dbo_DataLog (ProductionDate,ProductionOrder,StyleID) values (@ProductionDate,@ProductionOrder,@StyleID);Insert into dbo_WeightAndWidth (Data_ID,LabTech_ID,PunchWeight,OverallWidth,UsableWidth,GSM) values (@Data_ID,@LabTech_ID,@PunchWeight,@OverallWidth,@UsableWidth,@GSM) "
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductionDate", dtpDate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductionOrder", txtProdOrder.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StyleID", StyleID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_ID", value + 1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabTech_ID", "5")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PunchWeight", txtPW.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OverallWidth", txtOW.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsableWidth", txtUW.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GSM", txtGSM.Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()



        myconnection.Close()
```

Comment: Look for an equivalent to the C [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) function.

Comment: you got me on the right track; ended up getting it to work by using Select seq from sqlite_sequence where name='dbo_DataLog'

Comment: is it appropriate to run multiple sql statments like this and add the values or should I do separate "cmd"s